# Ubuntu Linux -- How do I start bitcoind as a service to run automatically?

Tags: bitcoind, services, server, ubuntu, daemon

I've got a bunch of other services set up to boot automatically when my Ubuntu server starts (services like wicd-daemon and VPN), but I can't figure out how to set up the bitcoin daemon (bitcoind) to start automatically when the system boots up. (This is on a headless system with no GUI or attached monitor.)

I'm trying to learn how to integrate bitcoin with Python so I can write bitcoin-enabled services, but I want the system to automatically start bitcoind when the system boots so that I don't have to do it manually. (It's a pain in the butt to have to download a whole bunch of block-chain at once. It eats away at uptime.)

If this question has already been asked, please direct me to the answer. I searched but couldn't find it. Otherwise, please help me figure this out!

Thanks so much.

Comment: see this directory: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/init it has startup scripts for many init systems

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT**: Caveat emptor on Ubuntu distributions from 14.10 and forward - [`init` was chosen over `upstart` and is being phased in the future](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316). I don't know when that will be done nor what impact it will have on upstart scripts.

[Extract from the page RentFree refers to](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25518.0); note that it assumes that you have created a user called `bitcoinuser` for the sake of security:

> For those running ubuntu, you may be familiar with [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), a replacement for `sysvinit` style booting (`/etc/init.d/*`).
>
> Configuration files for upstart are stored under `/etc/init/*.conf`. I've written the following one for bitcoind:
>
> ```
> description "bitcoind"
>
> start on filesystem
> stop on runlevel [!2345]
> oom score -500
> expect fork
> respawn
> respawn limit 10 60 # 10 times in 60 seconds
>
> script
> user=bitcoinuser
> home=/home/$user
> cmd=$home/bin/bitcoind
> pidfile=$home/bitcoind.pid
> # Don't change anything below here unless you know what you're doing
> [[ -e $pidfile && ! -d "/proc/$(cat $pidfile)" ]] && rm $pidfile
> [[ -e $pidfile && "$(cat /proc/$(cat $pidfile)/cmdline)" != $cmd* ]] && rm $pidfile
> exec start-stop-daemon --start -c $user --chdir $home --pidfile $pidfile --startas $cmd -b -m
> end script
> ```
>
> Put the above configuration in `/etc/init/bitcoind.conf`, then run `sudo initctl reload-configuration`. To start `bitcoind`, run `sudo start bitcoind`. To stop `bitcoind`, run `sudo stop bitcoind`.
>
> You'll probably want to change the **user**, **cmd** and **pidfile** to something that matches your configuration, or you can use the following as a template:
>
> ```
> /home/bitcoinuser
> /home/bitcoinuser/bitcoind.pid
> /home/bitcoinuser/bin/bitcoind
> ```

Though one user suggests the following correction to the configuration:

> ```
> home=/home/$user
> cmd=/usr/bin/bitcoind
> pidfile=$home/.bitcoin/bitcoind.pid
> ```

and another suggests setting `nice` for the process so it doesn't hog the CPU

> ```
> exec start-stop-daemon --start -c $user --chdir $home --pidfile $pidfile --startas $cmd -b --nicelevel 15 -m
> ```

Comment: Though this works, the upstart log shows some lines like this: `/proc/self/fd/9: 9: /proc/self/fd/9: [[: not found`. What's that?

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, try `pastebinit -i /etc/init/bitcoind.conf`, which will give output a URL with the configuration copied to a publicly accessible page. Double check the URL to make sure that nothing private is in there, then paste the URL here.

Comment: Woah, didn't know `pastebinit` did exist, cool! Here it goes: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6691665/ but it's pretty much copy and paste from here.

Comment: I don't really see anything that should cause problems, but I haven't spent much time on `init.d`/upstart - [here's mine for reference, where I've set it to log and to be more explicit in its output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6691761/). Note that I use `bitcoinuser` as the dedicated user. An aside about `pastebinit`: You can also pipe to it for command output - [more info here](http://explainshell.com/explain/1/pastebinit).

Comment: This answer is *almost* correct. You should change `expect daemon` to `expect fork` and `oom never` to `oom score -500`. For more details see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25731881/1157309

Comment: @c.hill, you can edit the answers here :-) - I have amended as suggested

Answer (score 12):

There's an [upstart script for Ubuntu](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/2d782ab2ce30bf106e34cd3288c9082ac04022f9/contrib/init/bitcoind.conf) in the Bitcoin Core source tree.  Using that is the most correct way.

However, I just login as the user account I want to run Bitcoin Core daemon, start a terminal (if I'm in the GUI), and run the following command to edit my crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I add the following line:

```
@reboot bitcoind -daemon
```

Save the file and exit.  Now every time the computer boots up, Bitcoin Core daemon will be started.  On shutdown, init/upstart/systemd/whatever will send it a SIGTERM signal, which bitcoind will catch and interpret as the command to start a safe shutdown.

Comment: but upstart is not used by Ubuntu anymore, right?

Comment: yes what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

I finally end up with this setting for my raspberry

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service
```

content of the file `bitcoind.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=bitcoin
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=pi
Group=pi

Environment=BITCOIN_PID=/home/pi/.bitcoin/bitcoin.pid
Environment=BITCOIN_HOME=/home/pi/.bitcoin

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bitcoind
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload systemctl daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Enabled new bitcoind service

```
systemctl enable bitcoind
```

Commands to start or stop the service

```
systemctl stop bitcoind
systemctl start bitcoind
```

Show service status

```
systemctl status bitcoind.service
```

More info in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/init

thanks for the help Janus Troelsen

**Update**

Don't put arguments since I have considered that there is a configuration in

```
/home/pi/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

Comment: nice one, but you missed a `d`: `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service`.

Comment: All good except you want `Type=simple`

Comment: @tread In Dogecoin, I had trouble getting `Type=simple` to work. I kept getting `dogecoind.service: Deactivated Successfully`. Only after I set it to `Type=forking` was I able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

I've never run it before. You said that bitcoind is a daemon, so here how to configure a daemon to run at startup :

Normally a daemon has its init script in `/etc/init.d/` directory.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bitcoind start
```

If the daemon needs to be initialized at startup, then it will be linked in `/etc/rc0.d/` or `/etc/rc1.d/` or ... `/etc/rc6.d/` ... etc

0 -> 6 are runlevels :

```
0 - Halt
1 - Single User Mode
2 - Multiuser
3 - Full Multiuser Mode
4 - unused
5 - Full Multiuser Mode with x11
6 - Reboot
```

you can also add the script that your daemon runs in

```
/etc/rc.local
```

If it is a python script you can write to that file :

```
python /directory/to/init/script/bitcoind.py
```

Another alternative is to execute `update-rc.d` :

```
sudo update-rc.d bitcoind defaults
```

`defaults` , will tells `update-rc.d` to run a default configuration, when it comes to runlevel . You can change your runlevel, this is an exampl :

```
update-rc.d bitcoind start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6
```

run `man update-rc.d` , there are other examples .

To remove it from startup, run :

```
sudo update-rc.d bitcoind remove
```

Comment: I think i removed `bitcoind` from my startup with your last command. Now it seems that I have troubles to activate it again. My bitcoind had a special working directory. I suspect that the startup skript contained this directory. Did I remove the file physically from `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/init` with this command? Because I dont have a file there any more which is related to `bitcoind`.

Comment: Ah, I have a `bitcoin.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` which contains the right path.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be your answer: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25518.0

Answer (score -3):

I've developed a script that may help you install AND run Bitcoin's CLI daemon at the same time.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
<your password>
y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
y
sudo apt-get install bitcoind
y
bitcoind -daemon
bitcoind -testnet -daemon
```

*The space between apt-add-repository and update is supposed to be there because of a prompt to press ENTER.