# Bitcoin mining on headless Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu, bfgminer

I've googled a lot and also read threads here but I'm still struggling.
Background:
I'm a eager but novice Linux user
I've an Ubuntu 12.04 webserver sitting pretty and is not doing much.
I would like to use the free processing power to mine Bitcoins - makes cents (sense).

Thus, I have Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed bitcoind and made a bitcoind.conf file as per [Ubuntu Linux -- How do I start bitcoind as a service to run automatically?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13795/ubuntu-linux-how-do-i-start-bitcoind-as-a-service-to-run-automatically)
(Basically, copy and paste)

I've installed bfgminer and I've register an account with Eclipse Mining Consortium (eclipsemc).

Now my questions:

1. I've read the bitcoin needs to download a large data file (+- 6Gb). 
   I can't find any log files to tail.  How do I know bitcoind is
   working properly?

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep bitcoind
   1000     30080  0.0  0.0   9364   368 pts/1    D+   21:21   0:00 grep --color=auto bitcoind
   ```
2. When I run bfgminer (bfgminer -o http://eu.eclipsemc.com:8337 -u [MyUserName_worker] -p [password] -L bfgminer.log), I have to press "M", then "+" and enter "auto" before it will pick CPU 7 as the device.  How can I ensure that it will pick CPU 7 as the default device? How can I run this as a background process?
3. I still need a bitcoin wallet?  I'm using Armory on my Windows box, what is a compatible one for Ubuntu webserver?
4. How do I ensure that bitcoind and bfgminer doesn't kill my server?

Thank you very much!

André

Comment: A bit off-topic: it doesn't really make sense anymore mining Bitcoin with CPU, you do realize that?

Comment: @Jori Not even in a pool? Any suggestion on how to earn using free CPU power?

Comment: No, not even in a pool. I'm sorry. You could take a look at [LiteCoin](https://litecoin.org/) or some other [Scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) based cryptocurrency, but I doubt that you will make any significant profit on that too (unless you have some serious CPU power).

Comment: I don't think there is anything that will make you a profit purely from that small amount of CPU power, but you could share it for scientific purposes (which is unpaid of course) like calculating new prime numbers / molecule modeling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CPU based mining is not viable any more.  Even going to other cryptocurrency, which difficulty level should rise quicker as people mining bitcoin using hardware will mine these too.

Ah well, missed the bus :)